# stat_bin2d with fill based on success rate

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I have a table with following data:

```
> head(sweet)
  interval  urgency success
1     3138      761       1
2     3210     2189       1
3     3243     1256       1
4     8776      823       1
5     3094     1405       1
6     3137     1062       1
```

Success takes values of 0 and 1. I'm looking for a success rate for different values of urgency, so I draw a histogram like this:

```
ggplot(sweet, aes(x=urgency, fill=success==0)) + geom_histogram(position='fill')
```

[image: plot1]

Now I want to look at success rate for combination of urgency and interval, but similar approach does not help:

```
ggplot(sweet, aes(x=urgency, y=interval, fill=success==0)) + geom_bin2d()
```

[image: plot2]

Is there a way to make fill continuously show ratio of success/failure instead of useless binary value on a 2d bin plot?

Comment: Do you have multiple observations per `urgency` x `interval` combination? If not, what ratio would you like to be plotted?

Comment: Make your example reproducible, either making sweet available, e.g. Using `dput`, or use a dataset included with R or, or create a mockup dataset.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein yes, I have around 100k observations total

Comment: @PaulHiemstra https://dl.dropbox.com/u/972870/sweetspot2.csv - here you are, just ignore day_of_week column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stat_summary2d`:

```
ggplot(sweet, aes(interval, urgency, z = success)) + stat_summary2d()
```

[image]